# jquery menu buttons mouseover effect

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-animate

I have two divs. One is position:absolute (.buttonEffectWrapper), over the top of the other div (called .rightColumnButtonHighlighted).

I also have the following JS code:

```
$(function(){
 $('.buttonEffectWrapper')
  .mouseover(function(){
   $('.rightColumnButtonHighlighted').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {duration:300})
  })
  .mouseout(function(){
     $('.rightColumnButtonHighlighted').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, {duration:300})
  })
});
```

It works fine, except it applies to *all* the divs. I need it to only apply to the current div, and I am not sure how to do that.

DIVS:

```
<div class="buttonEffectWrapper"></div>
<div id="rightColumnButtonText" >CAR SERVICE</div>
<div id="car-service-highlighted" class="rightColumnButtonHighlighted"></div>

<div class="buttonEffectWrapper"></div>
<div id="rightColumnButtonText" >TRAILER HAULING</div>
<div id="trailer-hauling-highlighted" class="rightColumnButtonHighlighted"></div>
```

See http://www.raceramps.com/v2 for the effect.

Comment: Does your HTML really look like that? The name "buttonEffectWrapper" would suggest that the two DIVs that are under it would be inside that DIV ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.buttonEffectWrapper').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.rightColumnButtonHighlighted:first').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {duration:300});
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings('.rightColumnButtonHighlighted:first').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, {duration:300})
})
```

Comment: Yours works just as well as the final result I came up with, so you get the vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function(){
    $( '.buttonEffectWrapper' ).mouseover ( function () {
        $( this ).next ( '.rightColumnButtonHighlighted' ).stop ().animate ( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 300 } );
    } ).mouseout ( function () {
        $( this ).next ( '.rightColumnButtonHighlighted' ).stop ().animate ( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 300 } );
    } );
} );
```

You ware attaching a "hover" event handler to every matched DIV which is OK, but then in your functions you animated all the DIVs not just the current one.
$(this) inside the function refers to the current element.

ps: you can use the [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) helper in jQuery to make the code a little bit more readable:

```
$(function(){
    $( '.buttonEffectWrapper' ).hover (
        function () {
            $( this ).next ( '.rightColumnButtonHighlighted' ).stop ().animate ( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 300 } );
        },
        function () {
            $( this ).next ( '.rightColumnButtonHighlighted' ).stop ().animate ( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 300 } );
        }
    );
} );
```

I've updated the code. Use `next()` to get the next element after `$(this)`

Comment: thank you for the info about $(this). Unfortunately, I was looking more for the effect to be triggered by .buttonEffectWrapper, but be applied to the sibling .rightColumnButtonHighlighted.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're selecting all of the elements with class "rightColumnButtonText". You need to do a `$(this).siblings('.rightColumnButtonText').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {duration:300})`

Comment: this may get me on the right track. It's actually a sibling, not a child. there is a sibling () right?

Comment: siblings() is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('.buttonEffectWrapper')

        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).sibling('.rightColumnButtonHighlighted').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, {duration:300}
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
                    $(this).sibling('.rightColumnButtonHighlighted').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, {duration:300}
        })
});
</script>
```

that should work right? somethings not quite right about it though....

Answer (score 0):

Final working code...thanks all!

```
$(function(){
    $( '.buttonEffectWrapper' ).hover (
        function () {

            var effect = $(this).siblings().filter(":last");
            effect.stop ().animate ( { opacity: 1 }, { duration: 300 } );

        },
        function () {
                    var effect = $(this).siblings().filter(":last");
                  effect.stop ().animate ( { opacity: 0 }, { duration: 300 } );

        }
    );
} );
```